# Upper bound to the Wright omega function

Tags: special-functions

I am looking for a reference describing upper bounds to the Wright omega function.

Thanks very much in advance !

Comment: It might help if you told us what references you already have, so people don't redo work you've already done.

Comment: You should email Robert Corless directly and ask. He's most likely to know. He may take a few days to reply, but he'll reply.

Comment: Thanks ! I am in the process of exploring the literature but, contrarily to many other topics, relevant results from naive search are quite scarce...